# Function expects Char in place of [Char]

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I am new to Haskell and functional programming, and can't understand why this function cannot identify the correct type:

```
mformat :: [Char] -> [Char] -> [Char]
mformat first last = ((formatted first last) ++ " " ++ first ++ " " ++ last ++ ".")
    where formatted (f:_) (l:_) = (f ++ "." ++ l ++ ".")
```

which causes the error:

```
teststuff.hs:42:40: error:
    * Couldn't match type `Char' with `[Char]'
      Expected: [[Char]]
        Actual: [Char]
    * In the second argument of `formatted', namely `last'
      In the first argument of `(++)', namely `(formatted first last)'
      In the expression:
        (formatted first last) ++ " " ++ first ++ " " ++ last ++ "."
   |
42 | mformat first last = ((formatted first last) ++ " " ++ first ++ " " ++ last ++ ".")
   |                                        ^^^^
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

I don't understand what is wrong here, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is `formatted`? Evidently, its second argument is supposed to be a `[[Char]]`, but you're trying to pass `last`, which is a `[Char]`.

Comment: @Brian why is `last` being treated as `[[Char]]` though?

Comment: In `(f ++ "." ++ l ++ ".")`, `f` and `l` must be strings since you're using `++`. You expect them to be individual characters though, in which case you should use `[f]++"."++[l]++"."` or `f:"."++l:"."` or `[f, '.', l, '.']`.

Comment: @StealthyPanda You depend on type inference for `formatted`. Try explicitly declaring its type to be what you expect. Then you'll get a more accurate error message.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is  in your `formatted` function. You are pattern matching on a `String`, you get `Char`s (`f` & `l`)  and then you try concatenating them with a `String`. You cannot concatenate a `Char` with a `String` (`[Char]`).

```
mformat :: String -> String -> String
mformat first last = ((formatted first last) ++ " " ++ first ++ " " ++ last ++ ".")
    where
      formatted :: String -> String -> String 
      formatted (f:_) (l:_) = ([f] ++ "." ++ [l] ++ ".")
```

or

```
-- ...
      formatted (f:_) (l:_) = (f : "." ++ l : ".")
```

The type checker thinks thinks that `f` and `l` in your case must be lists - because you are attempting to concatenate them. Then it infers (via pattern matching) from the list constructor, that `first` and `last` are lists of `Strings` i.e. `[String]` or `[[Char]]`.

Comment: Or, unrolling definitions and syntax sugar even further, `formatted (f:_) (l:_) = [f, '.', l, '.']`.